# Simplify Estimate Shipping Form in the Shopping Cart in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, shipping-methods

On the Magento shopping cart, there is always a default form for estimating your shipping cost on the shopping cart page, and these fields are always required,

```
Country
State/Province
Poscode
```

How can I simplify this form by requiring **Country input only**?

This is the Estimate Shipping code form list,

```
<ul class="form-list">
                <li>
                    <label for="country" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?><em>*</em></label>
                    <div class="box-input">
                        <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php if($this->getStateActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="region_id"<?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                    <div class="box-input">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isStateProvinceRequired() ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>>
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                        </select>
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                       //<![CDATA[
                           $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getEstimateRegionId() ?>");
                       //]]>
                       </script>
                       <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
                   </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($this->getCityActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="city"<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                    <div class="box-input">
                        <input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="city" type="text" name="estimate_city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateCity()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="postcode"<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                    <div class="box-input">
                        <input class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="postcode" name="estimate_postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimatePostcode()) ?>" />    
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

if I remove the fields of State/Province and Poscode **manually**, this form will not be working.

Any idea what I can do so there is **only** **Country** field is required?

But I **need State/Province and Poscode to be required** on my **Checkout** page though...

Answer (score 1):

You don't say here why the form doesnt work. I suspect its because you havent changed the javascript at the bottom to remove all the references to zipcode.

If still having problems then suggest set a breakpoint and debug this in the browser.

To debug in Chrome a simple method is right click and select Inspect element. Then you will see any errors that are thrown and can work from there.

Adding the line 'debugger;' in the javascript will help you step thro those issues.

In theory its possible to make this form just use country, as long as the underlying carrier supports this.